# Не убивается процесс после выхода из приложения WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Приложение выводит видео с web камеры. Индикатор загорелся. Нажимаю на крестик чтобы выйти из приложения, окно закрывается, а индикатор остался гореть. Т.е. процесс `FinalFrame` не закрывается.

```
CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        foreach (FilterInfo Device in CaptureDevice)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(Device.Name);
        }
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice();
        FinalFrame = new VideoCaptureDevice(CaptureDevice[comboBox.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
        FinalFrame.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
        FinalFrame.Start();
```

Comment: При закрытии окна, вам следует вызвать метод ``Stop()`` у ``FinalFrame``

Comment: я так пробовал. Приложение тупо зависло. Но не просто (Не отвечает) а просто сделало стоп. Только через vs стопить

Comment: Посмотрите первый ответ отсюда, по-моему это то, что надо: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780141/program-wont-close-and-aforge-camera-keeps-running-threading-trouble

Answer (score 3):

Благодаря [@alladuh](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1029661/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-wpf-c/1029676#comment1752546_1029661) проблема решена:

```
FinalFrame.SignalToStop();
FinalFrame.NewFrame -= new NewFrameEventHandler(FinalFrame_NewFrame);
FinalFrame = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте у окна событие Closing и вставьте следующий код, чтобы полностью убить процесс и дерево процесса

```
private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
}
```